# Jmeter - Network gets down if we run jmeter test

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I am facing some strength thing while performance test i.e. when I ran for 200 users with 1 sec rampup, it start failing after 100 users, but at same time when I checked server performance it shows alright(very less processor & Ram consumption).
Secondly when I try to hit same url after test completion from jmeter it shows not responding and at the end I have to restart my machine only then it start working.

I checked during test my machines resources remains small up and down.

Comment: Increase your JVM Heap size. Default is `HEAP=-Xms512m –Xmx512m`.

Comment: What do the Logs say?